# How to start serverless-offline in mocha test before function

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, serverless, aws-serverless

I'd like to use [serverless-offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline#usage-with-invoke) in some mocha tests. Something like:

```
describe('run some tests', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    // Start serverless-offline here
    return done();
  });

  after(function(done) {
    // Stop serverless-offline here
    return done();
  });

  it('run the test against serverless-offline', function(done) {
    // test code here
    return done();
  });
});
```

Is there a way to start serverless-offline programatically rather than via the cli? Or some other way to run tests on serverless functions offline?

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is use `concurrently` from npm (or a similar package that allows you to run multiple processes in a single command.

Then add in your `before` function a loop that waits for the server to spin up by pinging an endpoint with a HTTP client repeatedly. You can add either a default route or a health-check route to do this.